# Instantiate ViewController crashing on iOS 13

Tags: ios

App is crashing because of instantiateViewController() and it seems to affect iOS 13 users only.

```
let homeTabBarController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "home") as! HomeTabBarController
```

HomeTabBarController is a subclass UITabBarController. If I use a subclass of ViewController it works perfectly fine.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the exception message

Comment: As it stands based on the info you have given, the main possibilities are that there is no `"home"` identifier or, if there is, it is not a HomeTabBarController. If you want more help, give better info.

Answer (score 0):

It’s because viewController storyboard is maybe nil at that time, try this

```
var myViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("myViewControllerIdentifier") as! ViewController
```